# В одной из ячеек <table> происходит смещение из-за ячейки выше

Tags: html, css, table

Задача: разместить рядом с Address иконку карты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за длинного текста "#ABC (Text1 / Text2)" иконка ниже "убегает" от Address.
Если текст уменьшить - иконка станет ближе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код HTML:

```
      <div class="block">
       <div class="data">
        <table>
          <tr><td><h4 class="name">#ABS (Text1 / Text2)</h4></td></tr>
          <tr>
            <td><h4 class="test">Address</h4></td>
            <td><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
       </div>
       <div class="state">
         <table>
           <tr><td><h4 class="name">Состояние</h4></td></tr>
           <tr><td><span class="tag is-info">Готов</span></td></tr>
         </table>
       </div>
      </div>
```

Код CSS:

```
.block {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 1.8em;
  margin-bottom: 7%;
  border: 1px solid #77889978;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}
.data {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.35em; left: 1.3em;
}
.ev-state {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.5em;
  right: 1.3em;
}
.name {
  color: #C0C0C0;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Не использовать таблицы там, где они не нужны

Comment: Мне необходимо выровнять элементы другу относительно друга. Как это реализовать грамотно?

Comment: flex, например, или inline-block. С таблицей тоже можно решить, просто поместив иконку в одну ячейку с текстом. Но лучше от таблицы избавиться, это плохая практика - таблицы для таблиц.

Comment: @АлексГарисон, ну так они и выровнялись. Раз не устраивает, значит не необходимо.